# Joining multiple SUM into one result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

I have a table where I store the upvote/downvote of a user for a content:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
    (
      [ID] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
      [ContentID] INT ,
      [UserID] INT ,
      [IsUpVote] BIT
    )
```

IsUpVote is bit type above. Its value is 1 when there is upvote and 0 for down vote. I need to select sum of upvotes and doownvotes in a single query per content wise: I have written the following query to do the same:

```
SELECT  ContentID ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN [IsUpVote] = 1 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS [UpVotes] ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN [IsUpVote] = 0 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS [DownVotes]
FROM    @Table
GROUP BY ContentID
```

Output:

```
ContentID   UpVotes     DownVotes
----------- ----------- -----------
1           3           1
2           1           2
```

Is there any better way to write the above query performance wise or the abover query is fine?

Here is the data to populate the above table:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
    (
      [ID] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
      [ContentID] INT ,
      [UserID] INT ,
      [IsUpVote] BIT
    )


INSERT  INTO @Table
        ( ContentID ,
          [UserID] ,
          IsUpVote
        )
        SELECT  1 ,
                1 ,
                1
        UNION
        SELECT  1 ,
                2 ,
                1
        UNION
        SELECT  1 ,
                3 ,
                0
        UNION
        SELECT  1 ,
                4 ,
                1
        UNION
        SELECT  2 ,
                1 ,
                1
        UNION
        SELECT  2 ,
                4 ,
                0
        UNION
        SELECT  2 ,
                3 ,
                0 

SELECT  ContentID ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN [IsUpVote] = 1 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS [UpVotes] ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN [IsUpVote] = 0 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS [DownVotes]
FROM    @Table
GROUP BY ContentID
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably not get much faster than what you have, which is a single linear scan.

Here is a possible alternative query that might get very slightly faster results, but nothing to brag about:

```
select [ContentId],
       SUM([IsUpVote]) as [Upvotes],
       SUM(1 - [IsUpVote]) as [Downvotes]
from @Table
Group By ContentId
```

Note that if there is an index on ContentId, this will run faster.  Better yet, create an index on {ContentId, IsUpVote} so that the optimizer only has to consider the contents of the index.  You might pay for this in other ways, so think carefully before you do this.  (You will pay for this when you initially insert the data).